# How to perform LeftDoubleClick in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mouseevent

I implemented:

```
    <DataGrid Name="DataGridProcesso" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding  CollectionView}"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#D1DFE7" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
          <DataGrid.InputBindings>
              <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" 
              Command="{Binding ItemDoubleClickCommand}" />
          </DataGrid.InputBindings>
    ...
```

But the DoubleClick only work if I Click six times (3 double click)
I think the first click occurs in inner cell, after cell and finally in row (I only think, I haven't certain about that), I just want when LeftDoubleClick occurs in cell trigger my event.

What is wrong?

My full code of DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGridProcesso" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding  CollectionView}"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#D1DFE7" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
            <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding ItemDoubleClickCommand}" />
            </DataGrid.InputBindings>
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,10,0,10" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CCC"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Data" Width="Auto" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Data,Mode=OneTime}" ToolTip="Data" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Número"  Width="Auto" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Numero,Mode=OneTime}" ToolTip="Número"></Label>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Descrição"  Width="*" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Descricao, Mode=OneTime}" ToolTip="Descrição"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Andamento"  Width="Auto" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Andamento.Descricao, Mode=OneTime}" ToolTip="Andamento"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Lembrete"  Width="Auto" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Lembrete, Mode=OneTime}" ToolTip="Lembrete"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Part of ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Processo> _processos;
    public ObservableCollection<Processo> Processos
    {
        get { return _processos; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _processos)
            {
                _processos = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Processos));
            }
        }
    }

    private ICollectionView _collectionView;
    public ICollectionView CollectionView
    {
        get
        {
            return _collectionView;
        }
        set
        {
            _collectionView = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CollectionView));
        }
    }

    public ICommand ItemDoubleClickCommand => new Command<MainWindowViewModel>(a =>
    {
        AlterarProcesso((Processo)CollectionView.CurrentItem);
    });
```

Comment: can you show us the view model

Comment: Ok, I edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` to your `DataGrid` properties.

Then add `CommandParameter="{Binding CollectionView/}"`.

```
 <DataGrid Name="DataGridProcesso" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding  CollectionView}"  CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="#D1DFE7" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
      <DataGrid.InputBindings>
          <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" 
          Command="{Binding ItemDoubleClickCommand}"
          CommandParameter="{Binding CollectionView/}"/>
      </DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Note the `/` in the `CommandParameter` This ensures it binds to the current item.
Then when this is used with `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` it ensures that it binds to the selected item.

Comment: I'm already use IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"

If I use CommandParameter="{Binding CollectionView/}" in ICommand thow: Object should implements IConvertible

In my ViewModel I have reference to CollectionView, so I dont need the parameter.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that, did you try adding the command parameter?

Comment: Yes, but not work, I should click 6 times yet. Thanks